# Download image from json data to android Expandable ListView?

Tags: android, json

I am getting the facebook page information to ExpandableList. So i can easily get the posts and comments, but the problem is how to get the image from json?
the code works fine but the images does not display....

```
public class ParserPostJson {

     static Bitmap photo ;
     static String post_body ;

public static List<Post> parsingJsonFile(String result) {

    List<Post> postsList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    try {
        JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray rootJsonDataTag = rootJsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < rootJsonDataTag.length(); i++) {

            String body = rootJsonDataTag.optJSONObject(i).optString("message");// get posts

            String picture = rootJsonDataTag.optJSONObject(i).optString("picture");

            ///////// get created time for post
            String time = rootJsonDataTag.optJSONObject(i).optString("created_time");
            String created_time = getCreatedTimeForUser(time);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            ////// get comments.........
            String rootJsoncomments = rootJsonDataTag.optJSONObject(i).optString("comments");
            List<String> listOfComments = getListOfCommentForEachPost(rootJsoncomments);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            /// get name for each comment........
            String name = rootJsonDataTag.optJSONObject(i).optString("comments");
            List<String> listOfName = getListOfNameForEachComment(name);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            if (!picture.equals(""))
               {
                   photo = getBitmapFromURL(picture);
                   post_body = body;
                   Log.i("tooz", "kos");

               }
            else
            {
                photo = null;
                post_body = body;
            }      
            Post post = new Post(post_body, created_time, listOfComments, listOfName, photo);
            postsList.add(post);


        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return postsList;
}

private static List<String> getListOfNameForEachComment(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<String> listOfName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        if (!name.equals("")) {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(name);
            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++) {
                String nameOfComment = ja.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("from").getString("name");
                listOfName.add(nameOfComment);
            }
        }
        else listOfName.add("");

    }catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listOfName;

}

private static List<String> getListOfCommentForEachPost(String rootJsoncomments) {
    List<String> listOfComments = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        if (!rootJsoncomments.equals("")) {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(rootJsoncomments);
            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++) {
                String comment = ja.getJSONObject(j).getString("message");
                listOfComments.add(comment);
            }
        }
        else listOfComments.add("");
    }
    catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listOfComments;
}

private static String getCreatedTimeForUser(String time) {
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");

    String created_time = null;


    long when = 0;

    try {

        when = dateFormat.parse(time).getTime();


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy  hh:mm:ss a");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02:00"));
        created_time = sdf.format(when);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return created_time;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect(); 
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return myBitmap;
}   
 }
```

expandableAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    /// list of time for the post.....
    private List<String> _listOfTime;
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    /// list of names for each comment......
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChildName;

    private List<Bitmap> _listOfPhoto;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, List<String> listOfTime,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildDataName, List<Bitmap> listOfPhoto) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listOfTime = listOfTime;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this._listDataChildName = listChildDataName;
        this._listOfPhoto = listOfPhoto;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
     public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        final String nameOfComment = (String) (this._listDataChildName.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                childPosition));

        if (convertView == null) {

          LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);



        }
        TextView lblListHeadercomments = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.comment);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        lblListHeadercomments.setText(childText);

        name.setText(nameOfComment);
        // TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
//                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
// 
//        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);
//        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
//        if (convertView == null) {
//            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
//                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
//        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.posts);
        TextView created_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.created_time);

        ImageView photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
//        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
//        created_time.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
        created_time.setText(this._listOfTime.get(groupPosition));
        photo.setImageBitmap(this._listOfPhoto.get(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Context context = this;

private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeComponents();
    new AsyncTaskGettingFeeds(context,handler).execute();
}

Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String result = msg.getData().getString("Result");
        List<Post> postsList = ParserPostJson.parsingJsonFile(result);

        setAdapterForExpandableListView(postsList);
        return false;
    }
});

private void initializeComponents() {
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_view);
}

private void setAdapterForExpandableListView(List<Post> postsList) {
    List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Bitmap> listOfPicture = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    List<String> listOfTime = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChildName = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < postsList.size(); i++) {
        Post post = postsList.get(i);
        listDataHeader.add(post.getBody());
        listOfTime.add(post.getCreated_time());
        listOfPicture.add(post.getPicture());



        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), post.getComments());
        listDataChildName.put(listDataHeader.get(i), post.getNames());

    }
    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context, listDataHeader, listOfTime, listDataChild, listDataChildName, listOfPicture);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

}
}
```

post

```
public class Post {

private String body;
private String created_time;
private List<String> comments;
private List<String> names;
private Bitmap picture;

public Post(String body, String created_time, List<String> comments, List<String> Names, Bitmap picture) {
    this.body = body;
    this.created_time = created_time;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.names = Names;
    this.picture = picture;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
public List<String> getComments() {
    return comments;
}
public void setComments(List<String> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public void setCreated_time(String created_time) {
    this.created_time = created_time;
}

public String getCreated_time() {
    return created_time;
}

public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public List<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void SetPicture(Bitmap picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

public Bitmap getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

  }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error because you need to be getting the images in an AsyncTask

Comment: no, i dont get an error

Comment: What value you got on picture node of json array ? i mean is it the path to image or not ?

Comment: i get a url .....like this
"picture": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/1610029_832784456738168_1539142856_s.jpg"